# Linux with Libreoffice, nothing else!

Tags: linux

Is there any distro that lets you to run just one app? No updates, no network access, no other applications installed, only LibreOffice. I was trying to do it by removing all the packages from PuppyLinux and TCLinux, but it's too complicated without ruins the entire OS.

P.S. Arch Linux is not an alternative for me.

Thank you

Comment: No, because you need a lot of other applications to run LibreOffice. But you may want to start LibreOffice in a container like Docker, which could provide your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You could build your own linux kernel from kernel.org and then install everything by minimal - OpenBox as a DM for example. You probably won't find that kind of distros (or it's just me not aware of them), but you may ask your good linux-advanced friend to do this.

The plan is:
1) compile kernel.
2) install openbox.
3) install libreoffice and all it's dependencies.
4) creare user and strict it to use only libreoffice (if it is strict requirement or you don't want to force use it just install it).
5) create autostart script, configure auto-login if necessary.
6) create distro from your system.

You can find each of this steps on the Internet explained step-by-step.

Good luck!